# Python : Best way to grab a piece of string partially look like another string

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I would like to grab a piece of the string that may not be exactly matched.

for example:

```
str1 = 'invoice#'
str2 = 'sold to wal-mart corp invoice no 91058780'
```

expected output

> invoice no 91058780

The valid cases here for `str1`

```
Invoice number
Invoice Num
Invoice no
Invoice#
Invoice:
inv number
```

I have used the regex expressions but more substrings exist in between. 
Regex I have been using is `INV_regex = re.escape(str1) + r"\.?:?\s?\w+"`

some case will need more complicated regex to capture and it would be impossible to cover all these cases

Comment: I mean, how fuzzy do you want the regex to be? Do you want it to recognize "Inovice"? or "Invoice2"? Where do you draw the line

Comment: it would contain some extra letters in between as the above case `invoice no ` and `invoice#`

Comment: how many extra letters are allowed

Comment: it's dynamic can't control that

Comment: I mean, I just don't get what conditions there are. Would the following work? "invoicesdijgfklsdjhngkjsakjslkjfdk"?

Comment: @ahmedosama Please add some examples of input and outputs, it would really help us understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @RushabhMehta yes and also spaces in between. I will add more cases

Comment: So, would the regex r'invoice[a-zA-Z#+×÷=/_<>[]!@$%^&]*[0-9]*' work? Its not clean but it would kind of do what you want if Im understanding

Comment: @LucaCappelletti I hope this give you an overview about the use case

Comment: What I meant was both input and output: could you please also add the strings you would consider as source of these outputs?

Comment: ok, basically I have some keywords I search for in the document with fuzzy string match that calculates distance and the closest matches , return a line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use fuzzy match algorithms 
e.g.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

a = 'invoice#'
b = 'sold to wal-mart corp invoice no 91058780'

for word in b.split():
    print(a, word, '-->',fuzz.partial_ratio(word,a))

get_word = [word for word in b.split() if fuzz.partial_ratio(word,a)>98]

print(get_word)
```

as you can see below on jupyter notebook, it gets the value we are after. Will this work?
[image: Here is example]

Answer (score 1):

Just to see if I could do it, this should find the invoice and the invoice number based on the following assumptions

1. invoice is always present in the string
2. The numbers that appear after invoice are the invoice numbers.

I've put some garbage between invoice and the numbers just to ensure I'm able to extract them correctly. It won't take # or no or number. It will also ignore any numbers after it finds the first set of digits. I split str3 up, basically the loop is finding invoice and an digit. Once it finds a digit after invoice (str3 starts at invoice)

```
def isInv(strn):
leng = len('invoice')
print(leng)
pos = strn.find('invoice')
strn = strn[pos:leng]
    if strn == 'invoice':
        return(1)
    return(0)

def dig(strn):
    if strn.isdigit()==True:
        return(1)
    return(0)


str1 = 'invoice'
str2 = 'sold to invoice testing garbage 91058780 12345 wal-mart 12345673 corp'

fullLen = len(str2)
RelvLen = totalLen = str2.find(str1)

str3 = str2[totalLen:fullLen]


x = str3.split()

finlLst = []

for t in x:
    itm = isInv(t)
    if itm > 0:
       finlLst.append(t)
    itm = dig(t)
    if itm > 0:
        finlLst.append(t)

inv = finlLst[0] + " " + finlLst[1]

print(inv)
```

Comment: The case that in the middle may be valid as the invoice number may be in the middle

Comment: That too and a valid point. This assumes that the invoice is the last part of the string.

Comment: So I decided to see if I could solve it with just standard Python libraries by splitting the string up. Assuming you're comfortable with just getting INVOICE and the number (as well as the assumptions above) this should work too.